# ObservableCollection<EF4Entity> bound to ListView, but relation fields don't cause ListView to update

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, data-binding, properties, observablecollection

I have an `ObservableCollection` of Entity Framework 4 entities bound to a `ListView`. If I modify any of the normal, scalar properties of the entity, the values displayed in the `ListView` are updated.

Any relationship (navigation) properties are not updated in the `ListView` if they change, because the entity object doesn't implement change notifications for these properties.

Right now, I'm removing the entity from the collection and then reinserting it back into the same position to force the `ListView` to update.

There must be a better solution. What is it, if it exists?

Here's the generated code from VS2010's EF designer:

```
[EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="RovingAuditDb", Name="AuditRecord")]
[Serializable()]
[DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
public partial class AuditRecord : EntityObject
{
    #region Factory Method

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new AuditRecord object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">Initial value of the Id property.</param>
    /// <param name="date">Initial value of the Date property.</param>
    public static AuditRecord CreateAuditRecord(global::System.Int32 id, global::System.DateTime date)
    {
        AuditRecord auditRecord = new AuditRecord();
        auditRecord.Id = id;
        auditRecord.Date = date;
        return auditRecord;
    }

    #endregion
    #region Primitive Properties
    // Deleted for this post
    #endregion

    #region Navigation Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    [SoapIgnoreAttribute()]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    [EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute("RovingAuditDb", "AuditRecordCell", "Cell")]
    public Cell Cell
    {
        get
        {
            return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedReference<Cell>("RovingAuditDb.AuditRecordCell", "Cell").Value;
        }
        set
        {
            ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedReference<Cell>("RovingAuditDb.AuditRecordCell", "Cell").Value = value;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [BrowsableAttribute(false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public EntityReference<Cell> CellReference
    {
        get
        {
            return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedReference<Cell>("RovingAuditDb.AuditRecordCell", "Cell");
        }
        set
        {
            if ((value != null))
            {
                ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.InitializeRelatedReference<Cell>("RovingAuditDb.AuditRecordCell", "Cell", value);
            }
        }
    }
    // Rest of the Navigation properties removed for this post
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible to "auto-update" the UI if the object does not implement dependency properties.

Comment: @WileyMarques -1 if I could. Not true. That's what `INotifyPropertyChanged` is for. Let him post the code and XAML so we can understand the situation

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I had forgot `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: The code is the auto-generated entity objects from VS2010's EF4 designer. The default code generation. I'll post the auto-generated code I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those entities are not suitable for WPF two-way binding, which is based in `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I suggest you take a look at [Self Tracking Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff407090%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which are best suited for use in client/server type WPF application.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I'll check it out. I haven't seen the documentation you linked to before, many thanks!